# Trim zeros in the decimal

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, formatting

I would like to remove the extra zeros if they don't have any decimal values.  But if they have, I would like to show them.
[image]

In the picture, I want to height the unnecessary 0 from the 10.00 and 20.00.  But I want to show the other 3 records below.

I used c#, asp.net 4.0 and GridView to display .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see the picture, but it sounds like you just need a format string: The `#` character represents a digit if it's needed, and a `0` character represents that you'll always have a digit.  So a format string of `"#.##"` sounds like it might be what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Weight" DataFormatString="{0:#.##}" />
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have trouble with formats [Kathy Kam's .NET Format String 101](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kathykam/archive/2006/03/29/564426.aspx) is ultimate resource for you.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the "#" custom format character might work for you.  Take a look at the "Custom Numeric Format Strings" on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx

You will need to specify the "Format" for the column somewhere in your GridView configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could always go at it the programmers way.

Define a TemplateField that is a label and its Text property is bound like so: `Text='<%# WeightText( Container.DataItem ) %>'`.

Define the WeightText method in the code behind that takes the Container.DataItem as a parameter.

```
protected string WeightText(object dataItem)
{
   // cast it to your object
   MyObject myObject = (MyObject)dataItem;
   decimal d = (decimal)myObject.Weight;
   decimal fraction = d - decimal.Remainder(d);
   if(fraction > 0)
       return d.ToString(); // string with fraction (format this however you want)
   else
       return decimal.Remainder(d).ToString(); // string without fraction (format this however you want)
}
```